# Abelian extension of $\Bbb C$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Is there a field extension $K / \Bbb C$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(K / \Bbb C)$ is a non-trivial abelian group?

Of course $K$ should be an infinite (non-algebraic) extension of $\Bbb C$, so it has a transcendental element $t \in K$. I know that $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb C(t) / \Bbb C) \cong PGL_2(\Bbb C)$. On the other hand, in Galois theory, if $K/F$ is abelian, then any subextension $L/F$ is abelian. But this doesn't apply to the subextension $\Bbb C(t) / \Bbb C$ of $K/\Bbb C$ since it is not algebraic. What can I do then?

(Side note: I'm not even sure that $K \supsetneq \Bbb C \implies \mathrm{Aut}(K / \Bbb C) \supsetneq \{1\}$.)

Thank you.

Comment: If $K$ is chosen to be a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}(t)$ then the question is equivalent to asking whether a compact Riemann surface can have automorphism group a nontrivial abelian group. I believe the answer is yes although I don't know how to construct an explicit example, which necessarily has genus at least $2$. It looks like this paper might give examples but I can't access it: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/S0024610799007115

Comment: Regarding your side note, it's known that a generic compact Riemann surface of genus $g \ge 3$ has trivial automorphism group.